# How do I change a value in a line of an existing script to reflect the (numerical) folder name?

Tags: bash, shell, vim, jobs

I'm running a job where I have multiple folders (labelled 0 to 41), each containing an identical script which need the ninth line edited:

```
#SBATCH -J aXau19
```

X should correspond to the name of the folder (0,1,2... etc.)

I'm trying to figure out how to write a bash script to automate this rather than going in and changing them all manually.

I'm quite new to Linux but this is the general idea of what I want to do:

```
for d in */; do;

#open script.sh in vi

# move down eight, across 12

#go into insert mode

#delete x

#take the directory name (just the number, not the full path)

#insert the directory name in place of x

#save and exit

done
```

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If you have 42 scripts identical except for that ninth line, why not one single script (one dir level up) with a ninth line a) with a positional parameter reflecting the directory, or b) the current directory from the 42?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `ed(1)` and a shell `for loop` solution.

Ed should change line number nine and replace `X` with the directory name.

---

I have created a small scenario just to show how it is done.

Create a directory testing inside /tmp plus the empty directories 0 to 41

```
mkdir -p /tmp/testing/{0..41}
```

Check the directories

```
ls /tmp/testing
```

```
0/  1/  10/ 11/ 12/ 13/ 14/ 15/ 16/ 17/ 18/ 19/ 2/  20/ 21/ 22/ 23/ 24/ 25/ 26/ 27/ 28/ 29/ 3/  30/ 31/ 32/ 33/ 34/ 35/ 36/ 37/ 38/ 39/ 4/  40/ 41/ 5/  6/  7/  8/  9/
```

Create some files and write some contents on in.

```
for d in /tmp/testing/*/; do
  printf '%s\n' {1..20}'#SBATCH -J aXau19' > "$d"/myscript$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM.sh
done
```

Check the new created files.

```
ls /tmp/testing/*
```

```
/tmp/testing/0:
myscript11901287773897.sh

/tmp/testing/1:
myscript22167100654321.sh

/tmp/testing/10:
myscript267471903230794.sh

/tmp/testing/11:
myscript21767360022483.sh

/tmp/testing/12:
myscript282132941319693.sh

/tmp/testing/13:
myscript6970151065611.sh

/tmp/testing/14:
myscript11068731012744.sh

/tmp/testing/15:
myscript19107175771.sh

/tmp/testing/16:
myscript12252298818021.sh

/tmp/testing/17:
myscript105202172129231.sh

/tmp/testing/18:
myscript2567385425240.sh

/tmp/testing/19:
myscript29570230212538.sh

/tmp/testing/2:
myscript11241700021570.sh

/tmp/testing/20:
myscript31918599925170.sh

/tmp/testing/21:
myscript21633144421815.sh

/tmp/testing/22:
myscript855984144154.sh

/tmp/testing/23:
myscript141701948311464.sh

/tmp/testing/24:
myscript26914582213221.sh

/tmp/testing/25:
myscript269851807416209.sh

/tmp/testing/26:
myscript12238285945162.sh

/tmp/testing/27:
myscript8701215006016.sh

/tmp/testing/28:
myscript11741830229037.sh

/tmp/testing/29:
myscript37121942613269.sh

/tmp/testing/3:
myscript252821857619268.sh

/tmp/testing/30:
myscript17684744220712.sh

/tmp/testing/31:
myscript67311600129127.sh

/tmp/testing/32:
myscript108853017115842.sh

/tmp/testing/33:
myscript223492431721664.sh

/tmp/testing/34:
myscript2802185356971.sh

/tmp/testing/35:
myscript19012307732797.sh

/tmp/testing/36:
myscript24174670724297.sh

/tmp/testing/37:
myscript3019178819832.sh

/tmp/testing/38:
myscript264601159329258.sh

/tmp/testing/39:
myscript6962410715067.sh

/tmp/testing/4:
myscript262302179122509.sh

/tmp/testing/40:
myscript14175285225742.sh

/tmp/testing/41:
myscript1053466403145.sh

/tmp/testing/5:
myscript263762898927462.sh

/tmp/testing/6:
myscript152723179213229.sh

/tmp/testing/7:
myscript222431803611235.sh

/tmp/testing/8:
myscript25041944217942.sh

/tmp/testing/9:
myscript16570686525823.sh
```

Check the contents of the files.

```
tail -n+1 /tmp/testing/*/*.sh
```

Each files contains the following

```
1#SBATCH -J aXau19
2#SBATCH -J aXau19
3#SBATCH -J aXau19
4#SBATCH -J aXau19
5#SBATCH -J aXau19
6#SBATCH -J aXau19
7#SBATCH -J aXau19
8#SBATCH -J aXau19
9#SBATCH -J aXau19
10#SBATCH -J aXau19
11#SBATCH -J aXau19
12#SBATCH -J aXau19
13#SBATCH -J aXau19
14#SBATCH -J aXau19
15#SBATCH -J aXau19
16#SBATCH -J aXau19
17#SBATCH -J aXau19
18#SBATCH -J aXau19
19#SBATCH -J aXau19
20#SBATCH -J aXau19
```

Now to edit the files.

```
for d in /tmp/testing/*/*.sh; do
  printf '%s\n' "9,s/X/${d##*/}/" w | ed -s "$d"
done
```

Check the contents of the files that was edited by `ed(1)`

```
tail -n+1 /tmp/testing/*/*.sh
```

If I understand your question, that is what you're trying to do, less the vi/vim requirement.